# How to include all usernames after filtering

Tags: mysql

[image: my tables]

NOTE: the `p_date` is supposed to be in *dd-mm-yy* format but excel decided to be a jerk as displayed it as *dd-mm*.

Anyways, for my query, I wanted to retrieve the username and a counter for the number of times the user has published a message in a particular month.

This is the code I used:

```
SELECT users.username, count(*) 
FROM publishdate JOIN users 
ON publishdate.uid = users.uid 
WHERE MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(p_date, '%Y-%m-%d')) = 11 
GROUP BY users.username;
```

[image]

When I filter for November, I see that `ruby` has published twice in that month, but how do I include all users who have published `0` messages into the result?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `users` table on the left side of your query and do `LEFT JOIN` to `publishdate` table:

```
SELECT users.username, count(publishdate.uid) 
FROM users
LEFT JOIN publishdate ON publishdate.uid = users.uid AND
     MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(p_date, '%Y-%m-%d')) = 11 
GROUP BY users.username;
```

**Note:** Predicate `MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(p_date, '%Y-%m-%d')) = 11` has to appear in the `ON` clause of the query, otherwise `LEFT JOIN` will be equivalent to an `INNER JOIN` operation.

Comment: I realized that later, so i deleted my comment :-)